# Algolia in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, firebase, algolia

I am using firebase for my android application and am performing full text search using Algolia which is suggested by all the blogs. I have successfully developed the script and its functioning properly. Now I want to host the script to run 24* 7. As I have an azure account , how do I go about uploading the script ? I have tried uploading the following as a function , web app but have been unsuccessful .

PS:- I have tried Heroku but wasn't satisfied.

The Script.

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
    var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
var algoliasearchHelper = require('algoliasearch-helper');


// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

// configure firebase
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});
var database = firebaseAdmin.database();

// configure algolia
var algolia = algoliasearch(process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID, process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY);
var index = algolia.initIndex('books');

var contactsRef = database.ref("/BookFair");

contactsRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
contactsRef.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
contactsRef.on('child_removed', deleteIndexRecord);

function addOrUpdateIndexRecord(dataSnapshot) {
  // Get Firebase object
  var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();
  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
  // Add or update object
  index.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase object indexed in Algolia', firebaseObject.objectID);
  });
}

function deleteIndexRecord(dataSnapshot) {
  // Get Algolia's objectID from the Firebase object key
  var objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
  // Remove the object from Algolia
  index.deleteObject(objectID, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase object deleted from Algolia', objectID);
  });
}

var queries = database.ref("/queries");

queries.on('child_added', addOrUpdateIndexRecordN);

function addOrUpdateIndexRecordN(dataSnapshot) {
  // Get Firebase object
  var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();
  // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
  firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
  // Add or update object

  var collegeName = "";
  var query_ID_LOLWA= "";
  var year="";
  var query = "";
  var counter = 0;

  for(var i in firebaseObject){
      var c = firebaseObject.charAt(i);
      if(c=='/'){
          counter = counter + 1;
          continue;
      }
      else{

          if(counter==2)
              collegeName = collegeName + c;
          else if(counter == 3)
              year = year+c;
          else if(counter == 1)
              query_ID_LOLWA = query_ID_LOLWA + c;
          else
              query = query +c;

      }

  }
  console.log(collegeName);
  console.log(year);
  console.log(query_ID_LOLWA);
  console.log(query);

  const query_final = query_ID_LOLWA;

  var helper = algoliasearchHelper(algoliasearch("****", "****"), 'books', {
    facets: ['collegeName', 'year','priority']});


  helper.on('result', function(data,query_ID_LOLWA){


        data.getFacetValues('priority',{sortBy: ['count:desc']});

        console.log(data.hits);

        var path_query = "/queries_answers/"+query_final;

        path_query = path_query.toString();
        console.log(path_query);
        if(data.hits.length==0){
            console.log("No results");
            database.ref(path_query).push(-1);
        }

        else if(data.hits.length>1){

            var ID = 1;
            var counter = -1;
            var length = data.hits.length-1;
            for(var h in data.hits){
                counter = counter + 1;
                if( (counter%5 == 0) && (counter != 0)){
                    ID = ID + 1;
                }
                database.ref(path_query+"/"+ID).push(data.hits[h].uuid);

            }
            database.ref(path_query+"/totalResults").push(data.hits.length);
        }
        else{
            database.ref(path_query+"/totalResults").push(data.hits.length);
            for(var h in data.hits)
            database.ref(path_query+"/1").push(data.hits[h].uuid);
        }

    });

    helper.addFacetRefinement('collegeName', collegeName);
    helper.addFacetRefinement('year',year);

    helper.setQuery(query);



    helper.search();



  /*index.search(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(content.hits);

    for (var h in content.hits) {

    console.log('Hit(' + content.hits[h].objectID + '): ' + content.hits[h].uuid);
    }

        database.ref("/query_result").push(content.hits);
    });*/




}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *" *** but have been unsuccessful"*? Did you get any errors when you deploy your script to Azure? Or, can you please provide your `package.json` file?

Comment: no , i didnt get any errors , but the script wasnt working

Answer (score 0):

Without more details than `but have been unsuccessful`, the only advice one could give you is to follow the usual steps to get a time-based Azure function deployed.

The simplest way is to use the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/):

> - Login to your Microsoft Azure account
> - Create a **Function App** to host your function
> - Add a **Timer-triggered Function**
> - Select the `TimerTrigger-Javascript` template to get started

At this point, you'll have a function that runs every minute. You can check the logs to confirm it is working.
You now want to configure its frequency:

> - Update the function's **Timer Schedule** (in the `Integrate` tab) to set how frequently the function should run
> - Finally, replace the template's code with your own.

You can find a **[detailed tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function)** with explanations on how to achieve each of these steps.